# iOS save image to bmp file, the file info is from 640x480 change to 640x-480

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, bmp, bitmapimage

I use this method save image as bmp file, and original image size is 640x480

```
extension UIImage {
    func toData (options: NSDictionary, type: CFString) -> Data? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        return autoreleasepool { () -> Data? in
            let data = NSMutableData()
            guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data as CFMutableData, type, 1, nil) else { return nil }
            CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, cgImage, options)
            CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)
            return data as Data
        }
    }

    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mobilecoreservices/uttype/uti_image_content_types
    enum ImageType {
        case image // abstract image data
        case jpeg                       // JPEG image
        case jpeg2000                   // JPEG-2000 image
        case tiff                       // TIFF image
        case pict                       // Quickdraw PICT format
        case gif                        // GIF image
        case png                        // PNG image
        case quickTimeImage             // QuickTime image format (OSType 'qtif')
        case appleICNS                  // Apple icon data
        case bmp                        // Windows bitmap
        case ico                        // Windows icon data
        case rawImage                   // base type for raw image data (.raw)
        case scalableVectorGraphics     // SVG image
        case livePhoto                  // Live Photo

        var value: CFString {
            switch self {
            case .image: return kUTTypeImage
            case .jpeg: return kUTTypeJPEG
            case .jpeg2000: return kUTTypeJPEG2000
            case .tiff: return kUTTypeTIFF
            case .pict: return kUTTypePICT
            case .gif: return kUTTypeGIF
            case .png: return kUTTypePNG
            case .quickTimeImage: return kUTTypeQuickTimeImage
            case .appleICNS: return kUTTypeAppleICNS
            case .bmp: return kUTTypeBMP
            case .ico: return kUTTypeICO
            case .rawImage: return kUTTypeRawImage
            case .scalableVectorGraphics: return kUTTypeScalableVectorGraphics
            case .livePhoto: return kUTTypeLivePhoto
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I got this info when I use **file** command to see the bmp file info

```
PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 640 x -480 x 24, image size 921600, cbSize 921654, bits offset 54
```

Why 640x480 changes to 640x-480?
Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Help yourself by searching for 'PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format.'

Comment: Hint: top-down bitmap